# Angular fade transition not working

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to get the divs to fade in and out when they are being shown and hidden. It took a long time to get the divs to even show at all! So now I'm almost there, just need to get the transition to work. Here is a plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OtD2YXaQFNv2oe7LkR96?p=preview

```
  <div class="btn top-menu-button red" ng-click="pagearea1='show';pagearea2='';pagearea3=''">red</div>
  <div class="btn top-menu-button orange" ng-click="pagearea2='show';pagearea1='';pagearea3=''">orange</div>
  <div class="btn top-menu-button blue" ng-click="pagearea3='show';pagearea1='';pagearea2=''">blue</div>
  <br>
  <span class="template-panel red" ng-class="pagearea1">Red</span>
  <span class="template-panel orange" ng-class="pagearea2">Orange</span>
  <span class="template-panel blue" ng-class="pagearea3">Blue</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use `display: none` on the initial state of the div. And then with the class `show` add `display: inline` to the div that I wanted to show. I couldn't get that to work with the transition.

So this is what I did: I added `opacity: 0` to the initial state of all the divs. Then I put in `opacity:1` to the `show` class. The transitions started to work.

Updated plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RpqoXXHGBeYaBzIlD8Qb?p=preview

```
.template-panel {
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: display is not an animatable property.  Here is a comprehensive list of all CSS properties and whether or not they are animatable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties